# BREW MP needs signature file?

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

Qualcomm announced the new BrewMP OS. In earlier versions I downloaded signature files 
to run the app in device through App Loader. Is the signature file needed for BrewMP devices?
Can I check the app without signature files (downloading though ESN number)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like in BREW, [you need a signature file to run a BrewMP application](https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/prod/resources/devEx/library/techguides/c/General/Programming_Model/HTML/Brew_MP_application_files.html).

For a developer, there are two main types of signatures. A Test Enable signature ("test sig") is issued for a specific device for a limited time period, and enables the particular device to execute any application.

When the developer has finalized the app, the commercial code signature is issued. This sig will allow execution of the application on any BrewMP device that has the corresponding root signature installed.

[More information about Code authorisation on BrewMP](https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/prod/resources/devEx/library/techguides/CSK/Code_Auth_thru_Digital_Signing/Code_Auth_thru_Digital_Signing.pdf).